# What does it mean by "not recursively enumerable"?

Tags: formal-languages

I came across following therem:

> There exists a recursively enumerable language whose complement is not recursively enumerable.

Now, I know following definitions:

> - **Recognizable language** is one which have one-to-one correspondence with the natural number with the additional property that we could specify an algorithm to enumerate the language elements.
> - Given the string not in the **co-recognizable language**, we can give Turing machine which can eventually confirm that the string indeed does not belong to the language.

Then what does the above theorem mean?:

1. $L'$ does not have one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers?
2. We cannot give an algorithm to enumerate the $L'$s elements?
3. $L'$ is co-recognizable.

Comment: It means not (recursively enumerable).

Answer (score 4):

I'm using r.e. to mean "recursively enumerable" and co-r.e. to mean "the complement is recursively enumerable". I'm assuming by $L'$, you mean the complement of $L$.

To answer your questions directly:

1. This is not correct. Every language over a finite alphabet $\Sigma$ has a one-to-one correspondence to the natural numbers. To show this, you would have to construct a one-to-one function that maps the words of your language to natural numbers. This isn't difficult at all, but a bit technical, so I'm only going to sketch the construction: Pick some well-founded total order $\leq$ on $\Sigma^*$, for example the lexicographic order. For $w \in L$, define $$predecessors(w) := \{ v \in L \mid v \lneq w\}$$ to be the set of words in $L$ preceding $w$ according to your order. Define a mapping $f: L \to \mathbb N$, by $f(w) := |precedessors(w)|$, assigning to each word the number of its predecessors. You could then show that $f$ is in fact a one-to-one mapping. This construction works for any language, though it is not necessarily computable for all languages.
2. Correct, when $L$ is not co-r.e., by definition $L'$ is not r.e., so there cannot be an algorithm that enumerates $L'$.
3. Correct, your theorem says $L$ is r.e., therefore $L'$ is co-r.e. Note this follows from the first premise of your theorem, not from the latter premise. In general, $L'$ being not r.e. on its own does not imply $L'$ being co-r.e. In other words, there are languages that are neither r.e. nor co-r.e., see [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3203/are-there-languages-that-are-not-in-re-nor-co-re).

To elaborate a bit more on what the theorem means: It says there is a language $L$ that is r.e. but not co-r.e.

The important insight is that if a language $L$ is r.e. and co-r.e., then it is decidable. Assume you have a TM $M$ for enumerating $L$ and a TM $M'$ for enumerating its complement $L'$. Then you can build a new TM $M^\star$ for deciding $L$: For a given input $w$, $M^\star$ simulates $M$ and $M'$ in parallel. Since either $w \in L$ or $w \notin L$, one of $M$ or $M'$ has to enumerate $w$ eventually. At this point, $M^\star$ stops the simulation and accepts or rejects $w$ based on which of $M$ and $M'$ enumerated it. It follows that $M^\star$ halts on all inputs and accepts $w$ iff $w \in L$. Therefore, $L$ is decidable.

Based on this insight, if you can find a language $L$ that is r.e. and undecidable, you can then conclude that it cannot be co-r.e. Since if it would be co-r.e. it could not be undecidable.

The usual example would be some variant of the halting problem, e.g. $H = \{ \langle M,w\rangle \mid M$ is a Turing Machine that halts on input $w\}$. You should know that $H$ is undecidable. To show that $H$ is r.e., you would have to construct a TM that enumerates $H$. I'm only going to sketch the proof: Your TM $M^*$ would iterate over triples of the form $\langle M, w, n \rangle$ for a TM $M$, $w \in \Sigma^*$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ in some fixed order (e.g. lexicographic order). When looking at such a triple, $M^*$ would simulate $M$ on $w$ for at most $n$ steps. If $M$ halts on $w$ within these $n$ steps, $M^*$ prints $\langle M, w \rangle$. It's not difficult to see that $M^*$ will eventually print every pair $\langle M,w \rangle$ for which $M$ halts on $w$, as for every such pair, there is some $n \in \mathbb N$, such that $M$ halts on $w$ within $n$ steps. Therefore, $M^*$ enumerates $H$, thus $H^\star$ is r.e.

Based on knowing that $H$ is r.e. and undecidable, you can conclude that $H$ cannot be co-.r.e. which proofs your theorem.